# Подмена ip адреса

Tags: windows, ip, сокет

Программа подключается к серверу по ip адресу.
К сожалению, ip сервера поменялся.
Изменить с помощью редакторов exe программ - не вариант.

Есть какие-то варианты подменить ip адрес, к которому подключается программа?

Comment: Попробуй Reshacker или Restorator, если, конечно, у него это было в пропертях. (

В общем, вероятность очень мала.

Answer (score 1):

Вариант 1: попробуйте программку [Relay_Tcp](http://www.dlcsistemas.com/html/relay_tcp.html)
Вариант 2: поднять виртуальную машину со "старым" ip-адресом, а на ней сделать форвардинг на нужный ip-адрес.